# confused between choosing linear or nonlinear regression to model this data

Tags: machine-learning, model, curve-fitting

I plotted the data I wanted to make a model for and the result is as shown in the picture. I tried modeling it using a Sinc-function but i failed so
if anyone has an idea that would help. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QY17L.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First, please note that while using linear regression for this problem may let you fit these datapoints, it's not going to provide any information really about any future data. It may fit your test data if all of it lies on this same curve. If you're looking for something to predict future price you might want to consider a time series model.

However, if you're just trying use a linear regression to fit this data to that curve you have to get slightly creative. If all your features are linear and you're using linear reg, then one way or another you'll end up with a linear answer, which won't fit this model. So you will need to make your own custom features from your data. You can probably get a pretty good approximation for this using a 10th degree polynomial. So your features could be X (Years since 1992), X^2 (Years since 1992, squared), X^3, X^4, X^5, X^6 ... X^10.

A variety of other classifiers would also work fine, but you'll probably need to use some sort of time series model (LSTM for example) to get anything you can generalize to predict the future.

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that an LSTM is not always effective in predicting future pricing. This is particularly notable in stock market predictions as the stock price is not dependent on past pricing, but moreso on world events. At best, you'll end up with a single step prediction, which looks like it mimics the test data perfectly, but fails to fit to the training data.